# How to get the height of inputAssistantItem in keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, accessoryview

I want to get the height of the keyboard in iPad without the inputAssistantItem's height. I'm able to get the height of the keyboard with inputAssistantItem, but I couldn't find any way to get the height of inputAssistantItem.

Purpose: I'm having a custom keyboardInputView, and the height of that inputView should be exactly same as the default one. I'm using intrinsicContentSize of UIKeyboardInputView to set the height of custom inputView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the input view in `UITextField` its automatically set the height `UIKeyboardInputView` :

```
let textfield = UITextField()

textfield.inputView = yourCustomView
```

Comment: It won’t show same height for all devices- mainly iPhone X.